# Hall sensor square wave output

Tags: sensor

I have a question regarding the SS411 sensor.

I have this sensor mounted on a BLDC motor. The magnets (neodymium) are placed with 0.02 mm precision. When spinning at a constant RPM, the sensor output square wave has the low pulse longer than high pulse. At any RPM, it is up to 10 % longer for the low pulse but is not constant - it varies randomly.

I even made a test setup with 4 magnets to see if the low pulse length variation is related to magnets but it is not, the low pulse still varies ramdomly.

The pull-up resistor is 1K5 and the supply is 5 V.

Do you have any opinions why this could happen? I'm familiar with BJT storage time that affects the turn-off time - could that by the case? (the sensor has a BJT open collector inside, according to the datasheet).

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Storage time should just produce the same delay each pulse, not varying. Post a scope shot and a photo of the motor magnet/sensor arrangement, link to the sensor data sheet would be good as well. If it's o/c output, what pullup are you using?

Comment: Pull up resistor is 1.5kohm, supply is 5v, https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sensing.honeywell.com/honeywell-sensing-hall-effect-digital-position-ics-ss400-series-ss500-series-datasheet-32320997-b-en.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiFgomLjoTrAhVFqHEKHfGiDBwQFjACegQIARAC&usg=AOvVaw0Q9as6VZNu4OF3MGmXqFI_

Comment: Sensors are is slots that were CNC cut, everything is with 0.02mm precision